# vb.net string.Contains not working as expected

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim currentRow As String() = {
                "Search term",
                "Clicks",
                "Impressions",
                "CTR (%)",
                "Avg. CPC",
                "Cost",
                "All conv. rate",
                "Cost / all conv.",
                "All conv."
        }

        Dim strComp As StringComparer = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase

        Debug.WriteLine(currentRow.Contains("search term", strComp))  'True
        Debug.WriteLine(currentRow.Contains("clicks", strComp))       'True
        Debug.WriteLine(currentRow.Contains("impressions", strComp))  'True 
        Debug.WriteLine(currentRow.Contains("CTR (%)", strComp))      'True 
        Debug.WriteLine(currentRow.Contains("ctr (%)", strComp))      'True
        Debug.WriteLine(currentRow.Contains("ctr", strComp))          'False
```

Why is it that the last Contains call `currentRow.Contains("ctr", strComp)` does not find that string in the string array?

Comment: Which of your array elements equals `"ctr"` in your opinion?

Comment: Does it have to equal ```"ctr"``` won't contains do a partial match?

Comment: All your other matches equal some array element, as it's supposed to be. An array *contains* an element when some element *equals* the search string. If you want "contains" on elements too, that's double contains, one way of achieving which is `currentRow.Any(e => e.Contains("ctr", strComp))`.

Comment: Your title says `string.contains` but you are performing an `array.contains`.

Comment: @GSerg so something like this? ```Debug.WriteLine(currentRow.Any(Function(e) e.ToLower.Contains("ctr")))``` seems to do the trick. Or am I doing it wrong? @LarsTech, I see now that I made a mistake thinking that ```string.contains``` and ```array.contains``` are the same.

Comment: Apart from the `ToLower`, yes. Use the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0#system-string-contains(system-string-system-stringcomparison)) that accepts the comparison type.

Comment: You should use: `Debug.WriteLine(currentRow.Any(Function(e) e.IndexOf("ctr", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the replies that I received, it appears that this is the way to accomplish this:

```
Dim currentRow As String() = {
    "Search term",
    "Clicks",
    "Impressions",
    "CTR (%)",
    "Avg. CPC",
    "Cost",
    "All conv. rate",
    "Cost / all conv.",
    "All conv."
}
    
Dim strSearch as string = "ctr"
Dim bDidWeFindIt As Boolean = currentRow.Any(Function(str) str.IndexOf(strSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
Dim element As String = currentRow.FirstOrDefault(Function(str) str.IndexOf(strSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)

If element IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Found an element that contains "ctr"
    Console.WriteLine(bDidWeFindIt & " Found element that contains: " & element)
Else
    ' No element found
    Console.WriteLine(bDidWeFindIt & " Did not find element that contains: " & strSearch)
End If
```

--- Edit by Idle_Mind ---

Make "bDidWeFindIt" a `Boolean`, and reverse the order of your statements. Note the `If` statement now is just checking the value of "bDidWeFindIt":

```
Dim strSearch As String = "ctr"
Dim element As String = currentRow.FirstOrDefault(Function(str) str.IndexOf(strSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
Dim bDidWeFindIt As Boolean = element IsNot Nothing

If bDidWeFindIt Then
    ' Found an element that contains "ctr"
    Console.WriteLine(bDidWeFindIt & " Found element that contains: " & element)
Else
    ' No element found
    Console.WriteLine(bDidWeFindIt & " Did not find element that contains: " & strSearch)
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use StartsWith as well:-

```
Debug.WriteLine(currentRow.FirstOrDefault(Function(s) s.StartsWith("ctr", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) IsNot Nothing)
```

The above will return True.